# How to consider another Cartesian axis?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, equilibrium, statics

Well, I solved the problem. The point is that I used a x and y axis with x parallel to the inclination of the box, but I wanted to think differently, if one considers the y axis itself containing the weight force, I wondered if the angle between the spring and this axis would be 45 degrees + the angle between the spring, ie 45 + 36.87

[image]

Comment: To be clear, are asking if the angle the horizontal direction in the picture makes with the spring is equal to the angle the horizontal makes with the 0.4 meter incline plus the angle the incline makes with the spring? I think there must be more you are confused about than that.